# AngularJs: Sharing data across controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using super heroic [Angularjs](https://angularjs.org/) in my application. I have a couple of pages like `home.html`, `project.html`, `map.html`. Each pages has a controller associated with it e.g. `HomeCtrl`, `ProjectCtrl`, `MapCtrl`. In my `home.html` user can create a project or navigate to `project.html`. In `project.html` I have list of all projects. When user clicks on a project he is navigated to `map.html` where I have some information regarding to project. I am using `ngRoute` for routing between the views. I am facing some challenges to share data across the controllers. I have created a service called `dataFactory` which stores all the data retrieved from backend. In my `project.html` view, I load all the data from backend and store them in service. When user lands into a project I use data stored in the `dataFactory`. The concern is that when user refreshes the page when he is on the map.html, all the data which are stored in `dataFactory` are wiped out and not loaded back cause data loading happens in the `project.html` page. I don't know how can I deal with it. I can not make a call to backend in every controller to get the data. I am planning to load the common data in `app.run()` method. But in that case I have to `broadcast/emit` the events to notify controllers, which will also be messier and will eventually lead to errors cause I know my application is going to be a huge application.

Comment: have a sharable data inside a `service/factory`? and use that factory to share that across all controllers..

Comment: data is already in the factory. But when I refresh the page data is wiped out.

Comment: when you referesh page, all angular component gets reinitialize and re-register again.. I'd suggest you to look at [ng-storage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage).

Comment: Ok. I'll look into it thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution but it needs some additional configuration while making routes in your `$routeProvider`, You can resolve your route when you have your data fetch from the backend. By using this method if a user refreshes the page on one of your project it will receive the data first then display that particular page.

First you have to modify your `dataFactory` something like this

```
app.service('MyService', function($http) {
    var myData = null;

    var promise = promise || $http.get('data.json').success(function (data) {
      myData = data;
    });

    return {
      promise:promise,
      doStuff: function () {
          return myData
      }
    };
});
```

Then in your `$routeProvider` you could make route to resolve when your data is fetched (that is receives its promise) more over by using this method it wont make another data call if your data is stored.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/',{controller:'MainCtrl',
    template:'<div>From MyService:<pre>{{data | json}}</pre></div>',
    resolve:{
      'MyServiceData':function(MyService){
        return MyService.promise;
      }
    }})
    .when('/b',{controller:'MainCtrl2',
    template:'<div>From MyServic2e:<pre>{{data | json}}</pre></div>',
    resolve:{
      'MyServiceData':function(MyService){
        return MyService.promise;
      }
    }})
  })
```

I've a made a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1PnXLgi1Tn2mojDqq8y5) for demo. Fell free to ask any question regarding this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is something I wanted. I'll try it. If it will work fine then I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

when you refersh the page, the app module loads again wiping out all the stored vars. You can use sessionStorage or localStorage to maintain data.

Comment: When page is refreshed I need to load the fresh data. I can not use localStorage I have lot of different data. project list some other base 64 icons and many more.

Answer (score 0):

When you store your data into `service/ factory` store it in to your browser's `local storage` too. So, when user refresh the page, you can check whether your `local storage` has the data or not. If there is data in your `local storage` just save these data into your `service/ factory`.

That's all !!!

If you are struggle to implement these things please update me, I can help you on the code also.