# AngularJS: Multiple Controllers to a View

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

Nowadays I am playing with [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). I am confused a lot between controller, models and views. What I have understood so far is that, in MVC pattern we have following three:

**1) Model**: Model is any of the logic, or database or the data itself. In anguarljs, models are created using factories or services.

**2) Views:** View is how our data is represented or displayed to the user. This simply represents our model to the user.

**3) Controller:** Controller is something which controls. As written on  [Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/), controller is the brains of the application. The controller decides what the user's input was, how the model needs to change as a result of that input, and which resulting view should be used.

So by looking at the definition of controller I can say controller is the boss. It will be responsible for whatever will happen. In my application, I have couple of **models like project, shape, note etc**. What I am doing is I have created `factories` for each model. e.g. **ProjectFactory, ShapeFactory, NoteFactory**. And I have created `controller` for each one of them i.e. **ProjectController, ShapeController, NoteController** to control stuff regarding to project, shape and note. I am not sure whether it's correct or not.

In my application I have a couple of views as well i.e. `map-view.html, project-view.html`. For each view there's controller **MapViewController, ProjectViewController**. My project view need projects and notes. So I need to use ProjectViewController, ProjectController, NoteController in my project-view.html. I don't know how can I do so. I can create a ladder of controller like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ProjectController">
    <div ng-controller="NoteController">
        <div ng-controller="ProjectController">
        Project view goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it's not a good way to do so cause tomorrow I'll have large number of model so I can not create this ladder and also accessing the scope of parent will be a pain in the back. It will be like:

`$socpe.$parent.$parent.$parent.data='Set data.'`

Antoher apporach is that I can create services like **ProjectService, ShapeService and NoteService** and use these services in `ProjectViewController`. But that leads me to confusion since all the stuff which will be taken care by theses `services` should be handled by `controller` and these controllers should be used at multiple places/views. Is it correct or the controllers I mean angularjs controllers are different from MVC pattern controller? I am messed up with all these concepts.

Comment: The latter is the right approach in my opinion. One view, one controller and inject the services you need. This keeps everything nice and clean.

Comment: The latter one leads me to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36257080/angularjs-sharing-data-across-controllers

Comment: Depends on how you access your data, JSON file or HTTP, there is nothing wrong with calling the data when the view changes. If the data is the same and never changes use JSON, otherwise use HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Try using directives instead,

```
<div ProjectDirective>
    <div NoteDirective>
        <div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way, you get a chance to provide mvc for every directive, and you can have these isolated per directive.  Much easier to organize.

Example directive function,

```
        // Code goes here
var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);


(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  var projectDirective = function() {
    function controller() {
      this.hello = 'I am from project directive.';
      console.log('Not sure why this is not getting called');
    }

    function link() {
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: link,
      controller: controller,
      template: '<div>{{ctrl.hello}}<span ng-transclude></span></div>',
      //templateUrl: 'xxx.html',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      bindToController: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: {}
    };
  };
  app.directive('projectDirective', [projectDirective]);
})(angular);

(function(angular) {

  app.controller('ViewController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = "I am from ViewController";
  }]);
}(angular));
```

Comment: I am sorry to trouble you. I am learning these stuff. How will I access the methods which are define in controller of projectDirective in ProjectViewController. Can you please provide a plunkr?

Comment: you should read the angular docs.  you can access directive methods basically within the start and end tags of your directive template or directive tags.

Comment: Hi z.a I have created the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/kBQd6qjIA2YBJnjcEgod?p=preview I am not able to access variables of projectDirective's controller.

Comment: I updated the answer.  1- restrict should be EA, A for attribute as directive 2- Since you are transcluding other elements into the directive you need to use this. 3- you have a directive template so you need to use that as your html :)

Comment: Done. Thank you very much. I'll get the answer reviwed from team lead. Let's see how it goes :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107616/discussion-between-hitesh-kumar-and-z-a).